# Opencv sample in Qt crashes immediately with the error 'The program has unexpectedly finished'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I tried to create a simple Opencv application in Qt and upon running, the whole application is crashed. If I comment out the opencv related codes from the project, the project runs just fine.

What I did:

```
Downloaded the Qt 5.5.0 VS2013 64bit version   
Downloaded the OpenCV 3.0   
Downloaded the Cmake 3.3.2
```

There were already prebuilt binaries in when I extracted the Opencv package, But all tutorials on the net wanted me to recompile the source codes so did I. The package contains:

```
build
sources
```

created a new folder named `mymade` to hold the binaries next to the other two directories. So it now looks like this:

```
 build
 mymade
 sources
```

Steps:

- Fired up `CMake`, specified the source folder from the extracted files 
  and specified `mymade` as the output for binaries.
- checked all options that had a `opencv` in their names, plus Qt! and configured it and subsequently generated the files.

This is the resulting contents:

[image]

So all is done and I now need to build the binaries. I opened `OpenCV.sln` and compiled the release and debug binaries. The dlls are placed inside `bin` directory, and the lib files are placed inside `lib` folder.

Now it's the time to configure the Qt projects `.pro` file, so I used the header files from build directory, and for libs I used the lib folder from `mymade` folder. This is the first configuration that I came up with, which compiles without any linker issues, but crashes just immediately.

The initial changes in project file :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-10-06T14:04:20
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h


INCLUDEPATH += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//build//include
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//*.lib

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Doing this in project file as it was suggested by answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151412/opencv-with-qt-the-program-has-unexpectedly-finished) didn't do any good either:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-10-06T14:04:20
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h


INCLUDEPATH += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//build//include

LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_core300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_highgui300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_imgcodecs300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_ml300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_objdetect300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_photo300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_shape300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_hal300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_flann300.lib
LIBS += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release//opencv_features2d300.lib

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

This fails as well:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-10-06T14:04:20
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h


INCLUDEPATH += L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//build//include

LIBS +=-L"L://Apps_Installation_Folder//opencv//mymade//lib//Release"
LIBS += -lopencv_core300 -lopencv_highgui300 -lopencv_imgcodecs300 -lopencv_ml300 -lopencv_objdetect300 -lopencv_photo300 -lopencv_hal300 -lopencv_shape300 -lopencv_flann300 -lopencv_features2d300


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

So what is the problem here?

### Update

As it was pointed out by @Miki, Qt couldn't find the opencv dlls (the configs above were OK but), And to solve this problem, one only needs to add the directory containing dlls to the PATH variable, there you are good to go and everything should be fine now.

Comment: I have a running build with: `INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/include` `LIBS += -L/path/to/lib \ -lopencv_core \ -lopencv_highgui \ -lopencv_imgproc` So basically you should remove -L from INCLUDEPATH, and add -l instead of -L in LIBS (in second snippet)

Comment: @Miki: Im a little bit lost here, L is the drives name where the folders reside!, removing it makes the path invalid IMHO. doest it not?

Comment: I _think_ that you need to use -L on the path, and -l on the name of the lib to link, or directly -l on the full path of the lib to link. But I'd go with -L<path> -l<libname>. I'm not an expert here, but should work.

Comment: @Miki: If I understood you correctly, I did that as well and the problem persists , I updated the question to reflect my latest tries.

Comment: yeah, that was it.  Are the dll found in the PATH?

Comment: @Miki:dont know about that, ! I didnt add the dlls to the PATH if you mean that!, By the way I just palced the needed dll next to the built exe and it ran just fine, ! It seems Qt has problems finding the dll, how to fix that ?

Comment: it's not a problem with Qt. If dll can't be found in the PATH, they are searched in the folder with the .exe. If they are not there, than CRASH! Usually with a nice error saying that a given dll is missing, however.

Comment: well, at least it works. Please post a nice answer with the working configuration, so it'll be useful also for future visitors

Comment: @Miki: I didnt do anything! I just copied the dlls from the lib folder and placed  them next to the exe file and there it runs!
I just added a new PATH variable with the name OPENCV_DLLS , and saved it, still inside Qt it fails, Is there some special steps that I need to  take to get PATH variable get activated in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments to question it turns out that the program didn't find OpenCV dll.

You can:

1. Copy the required dll in the same folder of the .exe
2. Add the folder containing the dll to the PATH. You need to restart Qt Creator for changes to take effect.